# How to draw a label with separator in Install4j Configurable From

Tags: label, install4j

In install4j, I'd like to draw a label just like the 'Destination Directory' in the standard screen 'Installation location'

I've tried 'Installation directory chooser', but no such label displayed.
Is there any form component can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "Horizontal separator" form component with its "Text" property set to the title.